# D3js circles on a map with radius in meters

Tags: d3.js, geometry, geo

I'm trying to code a map with D3js which is very close [to that example](http://interactive.guim.co.uk/embed/lhaddou/berlin-wall/wallworld.html).

My biggest issue is that I wanted to make a fixed radius in meters, using .attr("r", the_value).

The map will be fixed, so there won't be conversions' problems after zooming or dezooming.

So my question is : do you think is it posible (maybe by using the "scale" value of the map), and how achieve that ?

Comment: I think it is, it's not really that good of a question though.

Comment: if you set up a scale that converts the meters of the map to the relative pixels of the drawing area, it could be achievable

Comment: Indeed scale is the right idea, but to get any real help on SO, you should have a small, specific question and should help us understand what you've already tried.  This helps us not suggest things you've already tried